# EditText's setError() crashes on some versions of Lollipop

Tags: android

- The crash only happens on few old devices, so far in two lollipop
  devices.
- I am using saripar library for validation.

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class TextView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.widget.Editor.showError(Editor.java:353)
            at android.widget.Editor.onFocusChanged(Editor.java:1117)
            at android.widget.TextView.onFocusChanged(TextView.java:8115)
            at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal(View.java:4946)
            at android.view.View.requestFocusNoSearch(View.java:7660)
            at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:7639)
            at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:7606)
            at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:7585)
            at com.aez.editprofile.ActivityEditProfile.onValidationFailed(ActivityEditProfile.java:621)
            at com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator.triggerValidationListenerCallback(Validator.java:721)
            at com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator.validateFieldsWithCallbackTill(Validator.java:697)
            at com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator.validateUnorderedFieldsWithCallbackTill(Validator.java:679)
            at com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator.validate(Validator.java:334)
            at com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator.validate(Validator.java:295)
            at com.aez.editprofile.ActivityEditProfile.btnSubmitProfileData(ActivityEditProfile.java:705)
            at com.aez.editprofile.ActivityEditProfile_ViewBinding$3.doClick(ActivityEditProfile_ViewBinding.java:96)
            at butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.onClick(DebouncingOnClickListener.java:22)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4764)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19844)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
         Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 24
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:401)
            at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:737)
            at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:674)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:75)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)

**Part of the xml**

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:theme="@style/TextInputLayout_Theme">

   <EditText
   android:id="@+id/LastNameEditText"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:hint="Last Name*"
   android:inputType="textPersonName"
   android:imeOptions="actionNext"
   android:theme="@style/EditText_Theme" />

   </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add your xml code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is looking , in my case the .seterror inside any **EditText** without support edittext
housed by

**`<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`**

is the issue so i had to remove support design widget , now its working fine.

this happens on my LG G2 Lollipop version & a low end Samsung on Lollipop.

sample of working xml

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:id="@+id/text_input_FirstNameEditText">


                            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                                android:id="@+id/FirstNameEditText"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:hint="First Name *"
                                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                                android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
                                android:theme="@style/EditText_Theme_without_Special"
                                android:textColorHint="@color/font_red"/>


                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```